# Program having trouble reading multiple lines in C

Tags: c

I have written a C program that takes multiple inputs in the following format: 
rounds -> rows -> col -> array initial values

I have no issue with the following input:
2 2 2 0 0 0 0

but once put into the other format which looks like this

```
2
2 2
0 0
0 0
```

I get a segmentation fault, which I'm not sure why. I feel like I have newlines accounted for. Here is a snippet of my code where I think the error is happening:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < row && !stop; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < col && !stop; j++){
        num = strtok(NULL, " \n");
        if (num == NULL){ //if the next character after whitespace is null/eof
            printf("Invalid input 1");
            stop = true;
        }else{
            nums = strtol(num, &str, 10);
            if (*str != '\0' && *str != '\n'){
                printf("Invalid input\n");
                return 1;
            }
            int curr = nums;
            grid[i][j] = curr;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to show your entire program as an [mcve]

Comment: Please post an [MCVE]. What are the declarations of `row`, `col`, `stop`, `num`, `nums`, `str`, `grid`?

Comment: Are you running this on unix (which uses `\n` for newlines) or windows (which uses `\r\n`)?